# The role of "yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores" and yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores" in deciding the no. of containers/node?

Tags: containers, hadoop-yarn

I am actually trying to figure out how many containers are there in a single node manager. On what factors does it depend? And what is the role of "yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores" and "yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores" in deciding the number of containers per node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default resource scheduler in yarn is [Capacity Scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html).

Capacity Scheduler has two resource calculators

1. [DefaultResourceCalculator](https://apache.googlesource.com/hadoop-common/+/e0c9f893b684246feb5b4adbb95a05a436cdb790/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/resource/DefaultResourceCalculator.java) (default)
2. [DominantResourceCalculator](https://apache.googlesource.com/hadoop-common/+/e0c9f893b684246feb5b4adbb95a05a436cdb790/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/resource/DominantResourceCalculator.java)

DefaultResourceCalculator uses only memory to compute available container

```
public int computeAvailableContainers(Resource available, Resource required) {
// Only consider memory
return available.getMemory() / required.getMemory();
  }
```

DominantResourceCalculator uses both memory and cores

```
  public int computeAvailableContainers(Resource available, Resource required) {
    return Math.min(
        available.getMemory() / required.getMemory(), 
        available.getVirtualCores() / required.getVirtualCores());
  }
```

`yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` and `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores` don't play any direct role in deciding number of container per node.

While requesting for resources application tells yarn memory and cores it require **per container**.

In mapreduce we specify vcores needed by `mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores` and `mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores`

In spark we specify vcores needed by `spark.executor.cores`

`yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` and `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores` are used to define min and max number of vcores per container that can be allocated.

Comment: Thank you very much sb'. Your information helped me a lot.

Comment: @shekhar when I run Spark on Yarn (using DefaultResourceCalculator), I set spark.executor.cores = 5, but in the Hadoop Web UI, only 1 core is used. Do you know why?

Comment: @MichaelDinh In DefaultResourceCalculator, capacity scheduler assigns 1 core per container as it don't consider cores at all, But normally it won't affect performance of your job unless cpu becomes bottleneck.

Comment: @Shekhar how does spark or mr request number of containers ? in spark spark.executor.instances is directly related to number of yarn containers it gets. So how does spark transform it into a parameter that is understood by yarn.

Comment: @nir spark application requests one container per executor instance.

Comment: @shekhar sorry I think I was not clear. I mean what yarn parameter determine number of container. I am guessing spark must be translating spark.executor.instance into something that is understood by Yarn.